# what does DefaultEdge.class mean in jgrapht example

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, jgrapht

**What does dot class mean in the parameter passed to Constructor**

I am using [jgrapht](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-demo/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/demo/HelloJGraphT.java) for the first time . I have this question

What are we passing to the constructor of the DefaultDirectedGraph class?
I mean what does DefaultEdge.class means ? There is no static field with that name inside that class. I mean what is actual being passed to the contructor of that class. What does the dot class mean there ?

```
DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g =
            new DefaultDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question only aims at the syntax, you might want to refer to the section **The .class Syntax** of the site about [Retrieving Class Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) from the oracle documentation. In general `DefaultEdge.class` is an object that represents the *class `DefaultEdge`*. This is an object of the type [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), and contains information about the class itself - e.g., which fields and methods this class contains.

In this case, this `Class` object is used internally, by jgrapht, in order to create instances of edges. When the [`Graph#addEdge(V,V)`](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graph.html#addEdge%28V,%20V%29) method is called, this `Class` object will be used internally to create an edge - particularly, to create a `DefaultEdge` instance.

There are various possible ways how this can be done exactly, but it will either boil down to calling [`Class#newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), or to obtaining a `Constructor` from the given `Class` and invoking [`Constructor#newInstance(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-), passing the given vertices as parameters.

<sub>Extended in response to the comment:</sub>

For the particular case of the `DefaultDirectedGraph`, the creation of the edges is done with an `EdgeFactory` - a simple [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) that creates edge instances from two vertices. This factory is used in the `addEdge` method:

```
@Override public E addEdge(V sourceVertex, V targetVertex)
{
    ...
    E e = edgeFactory.createEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex);
    ... 
}
```

This `EdgeFactory` is created in the constructor, from the given `Class` object (which may be `DefaultEdge.class`, as in the example) :

```
public DefaultDirectedGraph(Class<? extends E> edgeClass)
{
    this(new ClassBasedEdgeFactory<V, E>(edgeClass));
}
```

The `ClassBasedEdgeFactory`, in turn, does what I already mentioned: It uses the given `Class` object to create a new instance:

```
public class ClassBasedEdgeFactory<V, E> implements EdgeFactory<V, E>, ...
{
    ...
    private final Class<? extends E> edgeClass;

    public ClassBasedEdgeFactory(Class<? extends E> edgeClass)
    {
        this.edgeClass = edgeClass;
    }

    ...    
    @Override public E createEdge(V source, V target)
    {
        try {
            return edgeClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Edge factory failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

So to summarize: One can pass a `Class` to the graph constructor (for example, `DefaultEdge.class`), to simply tell him: "Whenever I want to add a new edge, then create a new instance of this edge class."

Comment: almost clear can you explain the last paragraph little more elaborately

Comment: @ysaditya Extended the last section a bit